# Evaluate $\int \frac{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{x} dx$

Tags: integration

I'm struggling to figure out where i am going wrong with this integral. Any help would be much appreciated. Attached below my attempt at the problem:

[Problem attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piNCC.jpg)

Comment: You made a mistake with the partial fraction decomposition near the end. Both your denominators as $v+1$ and that ain't right. One should be $v+1$ and the other $v-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Let $\sqrt{1-4x^2}=u\implies1-4x^2=u^2\implies-4x\ dx=\ du$

$$\int\dfrac{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}x\ dx=\int\dfrac{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{4x^2}(4x\ dx)$$

Answer (score 1):

with the substitution from above we get $$dx=\frac{u}{-4x}du$$ and our integral will be $$-\int \frac{u^2}{1-u^2}du$$